# Save excel worksheet to specific folder and filename based on same cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to save a copy of a worksheet to a specific folder based on cell B8 and name the .xlsx file based on the cell range B8 too.

For example, a user first creates a new folder named "test1", & then enters this folder name/text into cell "B8".  He/she will activate the macro after completing their work on the worksheet, & it will save a copy to the folder named "test1" and name the .xlsx file as "test1".  (*So the .xlsx file will be named as "testfolder1" and the folder where it is stored is also called "test1"*)

I am using the following code to save a copy of the worksheet to a folder. Just can't figure out how to include the cell B8 into the SaveAs line. Too new with VB to figure it out.

```
Sub SaveForm()

 exampleForm = Range("B8").Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveSheet.Copy
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    .Range("42:" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftDown                      
    .Range(.Cells(1, "J"), .Cells(1, Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Delete xlToRight   
    .Parent.SaveAs "C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\ExtractedWorksheet\" &  exampleForm & ".xlsx"                 
    .Parent.Close False
End With
End Sub
```

Appreciate any input and hopefully my ending goal is understandable.
-Thanks!

Comment: That looks like you've done it correctly. What happens? Do you get an error? Does your file get saved? Are you sure the path you've hardcoded in there exists? The only thing I can see that should be changed is to add `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` to your `With` section, just to be sure.

Comment: I don't get a error. The script works just fine.

Comment: Then you'll need to be more specific in what you're asking. `Just can't figure out how to include the cell B8 into the SaveAs line.` seems to be your question, but you state that's not the problem, and it doesn't look like it is.

Comment: Whoops hit enter by mistake.  What I want it to do is save the worksheet to the folder that is also entered in cell B8.  So it would save the worksheet As Range B8 and in the folder named B8

Comment: There would be a existing folder with a name that matches cell B8.  I want the macro to save the worksheet with the name that is entered into B8 (which the code above accomplishes) and place it to that folder that is entered into B8.  So C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\ExtractedWorksheet\'cell B8'\'cell B8.xlsx"

Comment: See if either of the 2 suggestions in my answer will work. The first assumes you're entering the path, _then_ entering the filename. The second just uses whatever is in `B8` as both the path and filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're after, give it a try:

```
Sub SaveForm()
Static Path as string
Static FileName as string

if len(Path) = 0 then
  Path = Range("B8")
  if right(Path,1) <> "\" then
    'make sure the path is "\" terminated
    Path = Path & "\"
  End if
else
  FileName = Range("B8")

  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ActiveSheet.Copy   'not sure why you're doing this, but do so if it makes sense elsewhere in your code
  With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    .Range("42:" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftDown                      
    .Range(.Cells(1, "J"), .Cells(1, Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Delete xlToRight   
    .Parent.SaveAs "C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\ExtractedWorksheet\" & Path & _
                   FileName & ".xlsx"                 
    .Parent.Close False
  End With
  Path = ""
  FileName = ""
End if
End Sub
```

If you call this code from your worksheet_OnChange event, then when cell B8 is updated, it will:

1. check to see if you have a `Path` stored. If not, assume this is the `Path`
2. If you have a `Path` already, assume this is the `FileName` and save it.

Leave the 'Application.ScreenUpdating` commented out until everything is working OK, then put it back in. Makes figuring out what's going on much easier.

**UPDATE** based on your latest comment on OP:

```
Sub SaveForm()

  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ActiveSheet.Copy   'not sure why you're doing this, but do so if it makes sense elsewhere in your code
  With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    .Range("42:" & Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftDown                      
    .Range(.Cells(1, "J"), .Cells(1, Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Delete xlToRight   
    .Parent.SaveAs "C:\Users\JohnSmith\Desktop\ExtractedWorksheet\" & _
                   Range("B8")  & "\" & FileName & ".xlsx"                 
    .Parent.Close False
  End With
  Path = ""
  FileName = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! What you provided is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome. Just be aware that if someone enters "name\" (with the trailing slash) in `B8`, that will break your code in all sorts of ways. Probably want to check for that first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that I have created for a project that I worked on.

1. I first named a cell (through Excel user interface-formula-name
   manager-define name) and called it prform_prnumber.
2. I passed the value in that to a variant variable in vba and called it prnumber.
3. I then used that variable as name in the exporttopdf method.
4. I kept the path as that of the workbook.

This code will run (once the button is clicked) in the active worksheet:

```
Sub exporttopdf()

Dim prnumber As Variant
Set prnumber = ActiveWorkbook.Names("prform_prnumber").RefersToRange

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/" & filesavename & ".pdf", , , False

End Sub
```